# C# Minecraft connection protocol error

Tags: c#, sockets, client, minecraft

At first, I'm sorry about my English :(

Today, I started to work about a project that should connect to minecraft servers.

So I looked at the connection protocol(http://wiki.vg/Protocol),
and saw that at first, the client should send the Handshake(with next-state 2 to continue).
I built it like this:

```
public void Handshake(int ver, byte status) //status = 1 for status, 2 for login
    {
        byte[] handshake = new byte[2 + ver.ToString().Length + IP.Length + port.ToString().Length + 1];
        handshake[0] = Convert.ToByte(1 + ver.ToString().Length + IP.Length + port.ToString().Length + 1); //packet length
        handshake[1] = 0; //packet ID
        byte[] Bver = ToByte(ver.ToString().ToCharArray()); //ver as a byte array
        Array.Copy(Bver, 0, handshake, 2, Bver.Length); //set Bver
        byte[] BIP = ToByte(IP.ToCharArray()); //IP as a byte array
        Array.Copy(BIP, 0, handshake, 2 + Bver.Length, BIP.Length); //set BIP
        byte[] Bport = ToByte(port.ToString().ToCharArray()); //port as a byte array
        Array.Copy(Bport, 0, handshake, 2 + Bver.Length + BIP.Length, Bport.Length); //set Bport
        handshake[handshake.Length - 1] = status;
        client.SendByteArray(handshake);          
    }
```

After that, the client should send the Login Start, so:

```
 public void LoginStart()
    {
        byte[] loginStart = new byte[name.Length + 2];
        loginStart[0] = Convert.ToByte(1 + name.Length); //packet length
        loginStart[1] = 0; //packet ID
        byte[] Bname = ToByte(name.ToCharArray());
        Array.Copy(Bname, 0, loginStart, 2, Bname.Length);
        client.SendByteArray(loginStart);
    }
```

After that, the server should send back the Encryption Request,
but the server sent nothing.

Where did I wrong?

Thank you for helping!

Jonathan

Comment: Are you sure that you reached the server? It looks like you are using a string as ip adress. c# has the IPAddress class for situations like that with built in to byte array functions. maybe string.ToCharArray does not parse the string correctly

Comment: yes, I am. because of 2 things: I built a class who connecting to the server, and I checked it with wireshark, and the requests have been sent

Comment: Without it, is that look good?